# How to make Sliver headers sticky inside other Sliver

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make nested Sliver headers sticky.

I am unable to make the 'today' header sticky under the 'bruh' header(which is sticky). make it feel like some collapsing headers.

can someone kindly give a hand

```
class ListExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListExample({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppScaffold(
      title: 'List Example',
      slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SoldEntryPage(),),
        _StickyHeaderDateSort(index: 34),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _StickyHeaderDateSort extends StatelessWidget {
  const _StickyHeaderDateSort({
    Key key,
    this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverStickyHeader(
      header: HeaderDatePicker(),  // this the 'bruh' sticky header
      sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: ShrinkWrappingViewport(   // THis me trying to nest silvers
            offset: ViewportOffset.zero(),
            slivers: [
              _StickyHeaderList(index: 10),
              _StickyHeaderList(index: 11),],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is what most of that code is doing

[image]

Comment: hey see this once:- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header

and 

https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers

Comment: I am using the first package, The issue is that I am unable to make headers sticky at the same time as described in the question @ParthPitroda

Comment: can you show some code so i can help you faster :)

Comment: if you need more than the code above here is whole [file](https://github.com/bihire/ikaze_management/blob/master/lib/components/sticky_header_list.dart) @ParthPitroda

Comment: what's the implementation of HeaderDatePicker() ?

Comment: well, 1) it supposed to contain a sticky header with some date picking buttons. 2) it must contain a sorted list of [today, yesteday, earlier this month, months(names), past years(names)] in that order that is why I need to nest sticky headers. @FrancescoIapicca

Comment: You might want to share a reproducible piece of code. The code that you have shared has several dependencies we don't have access to. Making it a chore to re-write the code as you have it, to then reproduce your issue and attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Lists inside lists isn’t what you want.
I created a package [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) that introduces a `MultiSliver` widget that should allow you to achieve what you want.

Every section with a sticky header should be a multi sliver with a SliverPinnedHeader and a SliverList. Then setting pushPinnedChildren to true should give the sticky header effect you’re looking for.

Comment: @pskink thanks! But perhaps you can open a new question and add some more details of how you want it to work so we can discuss it there

Comment: Can you use a `SliverPinnedHeader` inside a regular `SliverList` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a modified `flutter_sticky_header` you can achieve this, even several level's deep. The modified version can be found here: [pull request](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_sticky_header/pull/67).

You can use the modified version with:

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_sticky_header:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/UnderKoen/flutter_sticky_header.git
      ref: master
```

An example:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: List.generate(
    10,
    (i) => SliverStickyHeader(
      header: Text('Main Group $i'),
      slivers: List.generate(
        10,
        (j) => SliverStickyHeader(
          header: Text('Sub Group $j'),
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, k) => Text('Record $k'),
                childCount: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

This is an copy of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009926/6098780) by me.