# Create list with nested sticky headers

Tags: flutter

I have data that I would like to be displayed in a list, with the use of sticky headers to group each record. I have found plenty of examples on how to do this with on level, but I have two. So each record will have a main group and a sub group. So when the users scrolls I would like for the current main group as well as the current sub group to be sticky.

Example of data set

```
Main Group 1
    Sub Group 1
        Record 1
        ...
        Record n
    Sub Group 2
        ...
        Record n
    ...
    Sub Group n
        ...
        Record n
...
Main Group n
    ...
    Sub Group n
        ...
        Record n
```

I have managed to nest 3 ListViews and get all the data to render, and have also used a StickyHeader from the sticky_headers package to get the main group sticky, but when using a StickyHeader on the sub group, it just scrolls right passed the the main group

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int mainGroupIndex) {
    return StickyHeader(
      header: Text('Main Group: ${mainGroupIndex + 1}'),
      content: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        primary: false,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int subGroupIndex) {
          return StickyHeader(
            header: Text('Sub Group: ${subGroupIndex + 1}'),
            content: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int recordIndex) {
                return Text('Record: ${recordIndex + 1}');
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

The dataset would in worst case have around 100 records that are grouped in different main groups and sub groups, so it would be possible for to use shrink wrap to true in the nested lists, but if there is another way to avoid this that would be best.

Anyone have any ideas on how this could be solved?

Comment: Can you provide JSON data? I worked with something like this before. I'm interested in solving this. Kinda hard to produce sample data manually.

Comment: you might want to use ListView.custom to. A custom child model can control the algorithm used to estimate the size of children that are not actually visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create nested sticky headers by passing `ScrollController` of parent `ListView.builder` to both parent and child `StickyHeader`s so that both headers will be getting same scrolling related information.

I extended the classes `StickyHeader` and `RenderStickyHeader` so that we can add offset that will keep child header below parent header while scrolling.

Also note that here I assumed height of parent header and child header is same, if that is not the case then you should send your parent header's height as argument to `determineStuckOffsetWithHeight` method in `performLayout` method of `_MyRenderStickyHeader`.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        controller: scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int mainGroupIndex) {
          return StickyHeader(
            header: Text('Main Group: ${mainGroupIndex + 1}'),
            controller: scrollController,
            overlapHeaders: false,
            content: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int subGroupIndex) {
                final list = ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 10,
                  primary: false,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int recordIndex) {
                    return Text('Record: ${recordIndex + 1}');
                  },
                );
                return _MyStickyHeader(
                  header: Text('Sub Group: ${subGroupIndex + 1}'),
                  controller: scrollController,
                  content: list,
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyStickyHeader extends StickyHeader {
  _MyStickyHeader({
    Key? key,
    required this.header,
    required this.content,
    this.overlapHeaders: false,
    this.controller,
    this.callback,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          header: header,
          content: content,
          overlapHeaders: overlapHeaders,
          controller: controller,
          callback: callback,
        );

  final Widget header;

  final Widget content;

  final bool overlapHeaders;

  final ScrollController? controller;

  final RenderStickyHeaderCallback? callback;

  @override
  _MyRenderStickyHeader createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    final scrollPosition =
        this.controller?.position ?? Scrollable.of(context)!.position;
    return _MyRenderStickyHeader(
      scrollPosition: scrollPosition,
      callback: this.callback,
      overlapHeaders: this.overlapHeaders,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _MyRenderStickyHeader renderObject) {
    final scrollPosition =
        this.controller?.position ?? Scrollable.of(context)!.position;

    renderObject
      ..scrollPosition = scrollPosition
      ..callback = this.callback
      ..overlapHeaders = this.overlapHeaders;
  }
}

class _MyRenderStickyHeader extends RenderStickyHeader {
  bool _overlapHeaders;
  RenderStickyHeaderCallback? _callback;
  ScrollPosition _scrollPosition;

  _MyRenderStickyHeader({
    required ScrollPosition scrollPosition,
    RenderStickyHeaderCallback? callback,
    bool overlapHeaders: false,
    RenderBox? header,
    RenderBox? content,
  })  : _overlapHeaders = overlapHeaders,
        _callback = callback,
        _scrollPosition = scrollPosition,
        super(
          scrollPosition: scrollPosition,
          callback: callback,
          overlapHeaders: overlapHeaders,
          header: header,
          content: content,
        );

  RenderBox get _headerBox => lastChild!;

  RenderBox get _contentBox => firstChild!;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    assert(childCount == 2);

    final childConstraints = constraints.loosen();
    _headerBox.layout(childConstraints, parentUsesSize: true);
    _contentBox.layout(childConstraints, parentUsesSize: true);

    final headerHeight = _headerBox.size.height;
    final contentHeight = _contentBox.size.height;

    final width = max(constraints.minWidth, _contentBox.size.width);
    final height = max(constraints.minHeight,
        _overlapHeaders ? contentHeight : headerHeight + contentHeight);
    size = Size(width, height);
    assert(size.width == constraints.constrainWidth(width));
    assert(size.height == constraints.constrainHeight(height));
    assert(size.isFinite);

    final contentParentData =
        _contentBox.parentData as MultiChildLayoutParentData;
    contentParentData.offset =
        Offset(0.0, _overlapHeaders ? 0.0 : headerHeight);

    final double stuckOffset = determineStuckOffsetWithHeight(headerHeight);

    final double maxOffset = height - headerHeight;
    final headerParentData =
        _headerBox.parentData as MultiChildLayoutParentData;

    headerParentData.offset =
        Offset(0.0, max(0.0, min(-stuckOffset, maxOffset)));

    if (_callback != null) {
      final stuckAmount =
          max(min(headerHeight, stuckOffset), -headerHeight) / headerHeight;
      _callback!(stuckAmount);
    }
  }

  double determineStuckOffsetWithHeight(double headerHeight) {
    final scrollBox =
        _scrollPosition.context.notificationContext!.findRenderObject();
    if (scrollBox?.attached ?? false) {
      try {
        return localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: scrollBox).dy -
            headerHeight;
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore and fall-through and return 0.0
      }
    }
    return 0.0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a modified `flutter_sticky_header` you can achieve this, even several level's deep. The modified version can be found here: [pull request](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_sticky_header/pull/67).

You can use the modified version with:

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_sticky_header:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/UnderKoen/flutter_sticky_header.git
      ref: master
```

Using this implemenation you would need to change to a `CustomScrollView` instead of a `ListView`. Your example would look like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: List.generate(
    10,
    (i) => SliverStickyHeader(
      header: Text('Main Group $i'),
      slivers: List.generate(
        10,
        (j) => SliverStickyHeader(
          header: Text('Sub Group $j'),
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, k) => Text('Record $k'),
                childCount: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a great library that allows you to have multiple levels of nested headers and is highly customizable: [flutter_sticky_infinite_list](https://github.com/TatsuUkraine/flutter_sticky_infinite_list)

Check out the **working demo**: https://zapp.run/edit/z99i06vq99j0?theme=dark&lazy=false

For a simple setup with no nested headers you use it like this:

```
import 'package:sticky_infinite_list/sticky_infinite_list.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InfiniteList(
      builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        /// Builder requires [InfiniteList] to be returned
        return InfiniteListItem(
          /// Header builder
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              ///...
            );
          },
          /// Content builder
          contentBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              ///...
            );
          },
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now if you want to add a nested header you can just place `StickyListItem` anywhere in your widget tree:

```
contentBuilder: (context) => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: StickyListItem<String>.overlay(
            header: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, top: 4),
              child: Text(
                "NESTED HEADER 1",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            content: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 34),
              child: Container(height: 500),
            ),
            itemIndex: '1',
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: StickyListItem<String>.overlay(
            header: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, top: 4),
              child: Text(
                "NESTED HEADER 2",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            content: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 34),
              child: Container(height: 500),
            ),
            itemIndex: '1',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```